# Filter a table column using year in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table in which one of the columns is `m_date` with type `timestamp with timezone`.

I want to write a query to filter the rows where the year is 2020.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use a range query:

```
select *
from the_table
where m_date >= date '2020-01-01'
  and m_date < date '2021-01-01';
```

This can use an index in `m_date`.

Alternatively (but slower!)

```
select *
from the_table
where extract(year from m_date) = 2020
```